# Visualising a 1-(50,15,15) design

Tags: visualization, combinatorics

The problem I have is the visualisation of a $1-(50,15,15)$ design. That is a set of $50$ points and $50$ blocks (lines), so that each point is on $15$ lines, and each line contains $15$ points.

My attempts thus far have been on *Mathematica*. I have managed to create a graph with $50$ points and $750$ edges, so obviously the problem is putting $15$ points on a given edge.

Yes. I have generated a list of vectors:

```
U := {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 1 <-> 7, 1 <-> 8, 1 <-> 9, 1 <-> 10, 1 <-> 11, 1 <-> 12, 1 <-> 13, 1 <-> 14, 1 <-> 15, 1 <-> 16,
2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 2 <-> 7, 2 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9, 2 <-> 10, 2 <-> 11, 2 <-> 12, 2 <-> 13, 2 <-> 14, 2 <-> 15, 2 <-> 16, 2 <-> 17,
3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 7, 3 <-> 8, 3 <-> 9, 3 <-> 10, 3 <-> 11, 3 <-> 12, 3 <-> 13, 3 <-> 14, 3 <-> 15, 3 <-> 16, 3 <-> 17, 3 <-> 18,
4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7, 4 <-> 8, 4 <-> 9, 4 <-> 10, 4 <-> 11, 4 <-> 12, 4 <-> 13, 4 <-> 14, 4 <-> 15, 4 <-> 16, 4 <-> 17, 4 <-> 18, 4 <-> 19,
5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7, 5 <-> 8, 5 <-> 9, 5 <-> 10, 5 <-> 11, 5 <-> 12, 5 <-> 13, 5 <-> 14, 5 <-> 15, 5 <-> 16, 5 <-> 17, 5 <-> 18, 5 <-> 19, 5 <-> 20,
6 <-> 7, 6 <-> 8, 6 <-> 9, 6 <-> 10, 6 <-> 11, 6 <-> 12, 6 <-> 13, 6 <-> 14, 6 <-> 15, 6 <-> 16, 6 <-> 17, 6 <-> 18, 6 <-> 19, 6 <-> 20, 6 <-> 21,
7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 9, 7 <-> 10, 7 <-> 11, 7 <-> 12, 7 <-> 13, 7 <-> 14, 7 <-> 15, 7 <-> 16, 7 <-> 17, 7 <-> 18, 7 <-> 19, 7 <-> 20, 7 <-> 21, 7 <-> 22,
8 <-> 9, 8 <-> 10, 8 <-> 11, 8 <-> 12, 8 <-> 13, 8 <-> 14, 8 <-> 15, 8 <-> 16, 8 <-> 17, 8 <-> 18, 8 <-> 19, 8 <-> 20, 8 <-> 21, 8 <-> 22, 8 <-> 23,
9 <-> 10, 9 <-> 11, 9 <-> 12, 9 <-> 13, 9 <-> 14, 9 <-> 15, 9 <-> 16, 9 <-> 17, 9 <-> 18, 9 <-> 19, 9 <-> 20, 9 <-> 21, 9 <-> 22, 9 <-> 23, 9 <-> 24,
10 <-> 11, 10 <-> 12, 10 <-> 13, 10 <-> 14, 10 <-> 15, 10 <-> 16, 10 <-> 17, 10 <-> 18, 10 <-> 19, 10 <-> 20, 10 <-> 21, 10 <-> 22, 10 <-> 23, 10 <-> 24, 10 <-> 25,
11 <-> 12, 11 <-> 13, 11 <-> 14, 11 <-> 15, 11 <-> 16, 11 <-> 17, 11 <-> 18, 11 <-> 19, 11 <-> 20, 11 <-> 21, 11 <-> 22, 11 <-> 23, 11 <-> 24, 11 <-> 25, 11 <-> 26,
12 <-> 13, 12 <-> 14, 12 <-> 15, 12 <-> 16, 12 <-> 17, 12 <-> 18, 12 <-> 19, 12 <-> 20, 12 <-> 21, 12 <-> 22, 12 <-> 23, 12 <-> 24, 12 <-> 25, 12 <-> 26, 12 <-> 27,
13 <-> 14, 13 <-> 15, 13 <-> 16, 13 <-> 17, 13 <-> 18, 13 <-> 19, 13 <-> 20, 13 <-> 21, 13 <-> 22, 13 <-> 23, 13 <-> 24, 13 <-> 25, 13 <-> 26, 13 <-> 27, 13 <-> 28,
14 <-> 15, 14 <-> 16, 14 <-> 17, 14 <-> 18, 14 <-> 19, 14 <-> 20, 14 <-> 21, 14 <-> 22, 14 <-> 23, 14 <-> 24, 14 <-> 25, 14 <-> 26, 14 <-> 27, 14 <-> 28, 14 <-> 29,
15 <-> 16, 15 <-> 17, 15 <-> 18, 15 <-> 19, 15 <-> 20, 15 <-> 21, 15 <-> 22, 15 <-> 23, 15 <-> 24, 15 <-> 25, 15 <-> 26, 15 <-> 27, 15 <-> 28, 15 <-> 29, 15 <-> 30,
16 <-> 17, 16 <-> 18, 16 <-> 19, 16 <-> 20, 16 <-> 21, 16 <-> 22, 16 <-> 23, 16 <-> 24, 16 <-> 25, 16 <-> 26, 16 <-> 27, 16 <-> 28, 16 <-> 29, 16 <-> 30, 16 <-> 31, 17 <-> 18, 17 <-> 19, 17 <-> 20, 17 <-> 21, 17 <-> 22, 17 <-> 23, 17 <-> 24, 17 <-> 25, 17 <-> 26, 17 <-> 27, 17 <-> 28, 17 <-> 29, 17 <-> 30, 17 <-> 31, 17 <-> 32, 18 <-> 19, 18 <-> 20, 18 <-> 21, 18 <-> 22, 18 <-> 23, 18 <-> 24, 18 <-> 25, 18 <-> 26, 18 <-> 27, 18 <-> 28, 18 <-> 29, 18 <-> 30, 18 <-> 31, 18 <-> 32, 18 <-> 33, 19 <-> 20, 19 <-> 21, 19 <-> 22, 19 <-> 23, 19 <-> 24, 19 <-> 25, 19 <-> 26, 19 <-> 27, 19 <-> 28, 19 <-> 29, 19 <-> 30, 19 <-> 31, 19 <-> 32, 19 <-> 33, 19 <-> 34, 20 <-> 21, 20 <-> 22, 20 <-> 23, 20 <-> 24, 20 <-> 25, 20 <-> 26, 20 <-> 27, 20 <-> 28, 20 <-> 29, 20 <-> 30, 20 <-> 31, 20 <-> 32, 20 <-> 33, 20 <-> 34, 20 <-> 35, 21 <-> 22, 21 <-> 23, 21 <-> 24, 21 <-> 25, 21 <-> 26, 21 <-> 27, 21 <-> 28, 21 <-> 29, 21 <-> 30, 21 <-> 31, 21 <-> 32, 21 <-> 33, 21 <-> 34, 21 <-> 35, 21 <-> 36, 22 <-> 23, 22 <-> 24, 22 <-> 25, 22 <-> 26, 22 <-> 27, 22 <-> 28, 22 <-> 29, 22 <-> 30, 22 <-> 31, 22 <-> 32, 22 <-> 33, 22 <-> 34, 22 <-> 35, 22 <-> 36, 22 <-> 37, 23 <-> 24, 23 <-> 25, 23 <-> 26, 23 <-> 27, 23 <-> 28, 23 <-> 29, 23 <-> 30, 23 <-> 31, 23 <-> 32, 23 <-> 33, 23 <-> 34, 23 <-> 35, 23 <-> 36, 23 <-> 37, 23 <-> 38, 24 <-> 25, 24 <-> 26, 24 <-> 27, 24 <-> 28, 24 <-> 29, 24 <-> 30, 24 <-> 31, 24 <-> 32, 24 <-> 33, 24 <-> 34, 24 <-> 35, 24 <-> 36, 24 <-> 37, 24 <-> 38, 24 <-> 39, 25 <-> 26, 25 <-> 27, 25 <-> 28, 25 <-> 29, 25 <-> 30, 25 <-> 31, 25 <-> 32, 25 <-> 33, 25 <-> 34, 25 <-> 35, 25 <-> 36, 25 <-> 37, 25 <-> 38, 25 <-> 39, 25 <-> 40, 26 <-> 27, 26 <-> 28, 26 <-> 29, 26 <-> 30, 26 <-> 31, 26 <-> 32, 26 <-> 33, 26 <-> 34, 26 <-> 35, 26 <-> 36, 26 <-> 37, 26 <-> 38, 26 <-> 39, 26 <-> 40, 26 <-> 41, 27 <-> 28, 27 <-> 29, 27 <-> 30, 27 <-> 31, 27 <-> 32, 27 <-> 33, 27 <-> 34, 27 <-> 35, 27 <-> 36, 27 <-> 37, 27 <-> 38, 27 <-> 39, 27 <-> 40, 27 <-> 41, 27 <-> 42, 28 <-> 29, 28 <-> 30, 28 <-> 31, 28 <-> 32, 28 <-> 33, 28 <-> 34, 28 <-> 35, 28 <-> 36, 28 <-> 37, 28 <-> 38, 28 <-> 39, 28 <-> 40, 28 <-> 41, 28 <-> 42, 28 <-> 43, 29 <-> 30, 29 <-> 31, 29 <-> 32, 29 <-> 33, 29 <-> 34, 29 <-> 35, 29 <-> 36, 29 <-> 37, 29 <-> 38, 29 <-> 39, 29 <-> 40, 29 <-> 41, 29 <-> 42, 29 <-> 43, 29 <-> 44, 30 <-> 31, 30 <-> 32, 30 <-> 33, 30 <-> 34, 30 <-> 35, 30 <-> 36, 30 <-> 37, 30 <-> 38, 30 <-> 39, 30 <-> 40, 30 <-> 41, 30 <-> 42, 30 <-> 43, 30 <-> 44, 30 <-> 45, 31 <-> 32, 31 <-> 33, 31 <-> 34, 31 <-> 35, 31 <-> 36, 31 <-> 37, 31 <-> 38, 31 <-> 39, 31 <-> 40, 31 <-> 41, 31 <-> 42, 31 <-> 43, 31 <-> 44, 31 <-> 45, 31 <-> 46, 32 <-> 33, 32 <-> 34, 32 <-> 35, 32 <-> 36, 32 <-> 37, 32 <-> 38, 32 <-> 39, 32 <-> 40, 32 <-> 41, 32 <-> 42, 32 <-> 43, 32 <-> 44, 32 <-> 45, 32 <-> 46, 32 <-> 47, 33 <-> 34, 33 <-> 35, 33 <-> 36, 33 <-> 37, 33 <-> 38, 33 <-> 39, 33 <-> 40, 33 <-> 41, 33 <-> 42, 33 <-> 43, 33 <-> 44, 33 <-> 45, 33 <-> 46, 33 <-> 47, 33 <-> 48, 34 <-> 35, 34 <-> 36, 34 <-> 37, 34 <-> 38, 34 <-> 39, 34 <-> 40, 34 <-> 41, 34 <-> 42, 34 <-> 43, 34 <-> 44, 34 <-> 45, 34 <-> 46, 34 <-> 47, 34 <-> 48, 34 <-> 49, 35 <-> 36, 35 <-> 37, 35 <-> 38, 35 <-> 39, 35 <-> 40, 35 <-> 41, 35 <-> 42, 35 <-> 43, 35 <-> 44, 35 <-> 45, 35 <-> 46, 35 <-> 47, 35 <-> 48, 35 <-> 49, 35 <-> 50, 36 <-> 37, 36 <-> 38, 36 <-> 39, 36 <-> 40, 36 <-> 41, 36 <-> 42, 36 <-> 43, 36 <-> 44, 36 <-> 45, 36 <-> 46, 36 <-> 47, 36 <-> 48, 36 <-> 49, 36 <-> 50, 36 <-> 1, 37 <-> 38, 37 <-> 39, 37 <-> 40, 37 <-> 41, 37 <-> 42, 37 <-> 43, 37 <-> 44, 37 <-> 45, 37 <-> 46, 37 <-> 47, 37 <-> 48, 37 <-> 49, 37 <-> 50, 37 <-> 1, 37 <-> 2, 38 <-> 39, 38 <-> 40, 38 <-> 41, 38 <-> 42, 38 <-> 43, 38 <-> 44, 38 <-> 45, 38 <-> 46, 38 <-> 47, 38 <-> 48, 38 <-> 49, 38 <-> 50, 38 <-> 1, 38 <-> 2, 38 <-> 3, 39 <-> 40, 39 <-> 41, 39 <-> 42, 39 <-> 43, 39 <-> 44, 39 <-> 45, 39 <-> 46, 39 <-> 47, 39 <-> 48, 39 <-> 49, 39 <-> 50, 39 <-> 1, 39 <-> 2, 39 <-> 3, 39 <-> 4, 40 <-> 41, 40 <-> 42, 40 <-> 43, 40 <-> 44, 40 <-> 45, 40 <-> 46, 40 <-> 47, 40 <-> 48, 40 <-> 49, 40 <-> 50, 40 <-> 1, 40 <-> 2, 40 <-> 3, 40 <-> 4, 40 <-> 5, 41 <-> 42, 41 <-> 43, 41 <-> 44, 41 <-> 45, 41 <-> 46, 41 <-> 47, 41 <-> 48, 41 <-> 49, 41 <-> 50, 41 <-> 1, 41 <-> 2, 41 <-> 3, 41 <-> 4, 41 <-> 5, 41 <-> 6, 42 <-> 43, 42 <-> 44, 42 <-> 45, 42 <-> 46, 42 <-> 47, 42 <-> 48, 42 <-> 49, 42 <-> 50, 42 <-> 1, 42 <-> 2, 42 <-> 3, 42 <-> 4, 42 <-> 5, 42 <-> 6, 42 <-> 7, 43 <-> 44, 43 <-> 45, 43 <-> 46, 43 <-> 47, 43 <-> 48, 43 <-> 49, 43 <-> 50, 43 <-> 1, 43 <-> 2, 43 <-> 3, 43 <-> 4, 43 <-> 5, 43 <-> 6, 43 <-> 7, 43 <-> 8, 44 <-> 45, 44 <-> 46, 44 <-> 47, 44 <-> 48, 44 <-> 49, 44 <-> 50, 44 <-> 1, 44 <-> 2, 44 <-> 3, 44 <-> 4, 44 <-> 5, 44 <-> 6, 44 <-> 7, 44 <-> 8, 44 <-> 9, 45 <-> 46, 45 <-> 47, 45 <-> 48, 45 <-> 49, 45 <-> 50, 45 <-> 1, 45 <-> 2, 45 <-> 3, 45 <-> 4, 45 <-> 5, 45 <-> 6, 45 <-> 7, 45 <-> 8, 45 <-> 9, 45 <-> 10, 46 <-> 47, 46 <-> 48, 46 <-> 49, 46 <-> 50, 46 <-> 1, 46 <-> 2, 46 <-> 3, 46 <-> 4, 46 <-> 5, 46 <-> 6, 46 <-> 7, 46 <-> 8, 46 <-> 9, 46 <-> 10, 46 <-> 11, 47 <-> 48, 47 <-> 49, 47 <-> 50, 47 <-> 1, 47 <-> 2, 47 <-> 3, 47 <-> 4, 47 <-> 5, 47 <-> 6, 47 <-> 7, 47 <-> 8, 47 <-> 9, 47 <-> 10, 47 <-> 11, 47 <-> 12, 48 <-> 49, 48 <-> 50, 48 <-> 1, 48 <-> 2, 48 <-> 3, 48 <-> 4, 48 <-> 5, 48 <-> 6, 48 <-> 7, 48 <-> 8, 48 <-> 9, 48 <-> 10, 48 <-> 11, 48 <-> 12, 48 <-> 13, 49 <-> 50, 49 <-> 1, 49 <-> 2, 49 <-> 3, 49 <-> 4, 49 <-> 5, 49 <-> 6, 49 <-> 7, 49 <-> 8, 49 <-> 9, 49 <-> 10, 49 <-> 11, 49 <-> 12, 49 <-> 13, 49 <-> 14, 50 <-> 1, 50 <-> 2, 50 <-> 3, 50 <-> 4, 50 <-> 5, 50 <-> 6, 50 <-> 7, 50 <-> 8, 50 <-> 9, 50 <-> 10, 50 <-> 11, 50 <-> 12, 50 <-> 13, 50 <-> 14, 50 <-> 15}
```

Then used:

```
Graph[U, VertexSize -> Small, VertexStyle -> Black, EdgeStyle -> Gray,
  VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[20],
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

The problem here is that there are 750 lines. What I need to happen is:

`1<->2,...,1<->16` needs to be one lines, with 15 points on it.

Then the line `2<->3,...,2<->17` has 15 points on it and intersects the previous line at the point 2. And so on.

Comment: Share with us the code you have been using so far.

Comment: BTW, what does the `1-(50,15,15) design` means?

Comment: @Shutao, it's [block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design) notation.

Comment: So you want something like a [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) illustration but with 50 points and 15 of those on each "line"?  Sounds challenging.  Can you provide the actual block design?